# Export multiples RMarkdown Files

Tags: r, r-markdown

How can we export multiple markdown files (HTML, PDF, WORD) from R into zip file. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have to do this in bulk? Is there a reason why you cannot knit into each of the formats, and then manually zip them?

Comment: The `zip()` command will zip a list of files that you can specify.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?? Do you want to create multiple files of different output formats from one `rmd` file and then zip them together in one go?

Comment: Yes, shafee, this is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, we have the following `Rmarkdown` file (the source file) which can be rendered as pdf, html and word documents.

---

**multiple_output.Rmd**

````
---
title: "multiple outputs"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.


```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

---

Now to render this source file to pdf, html, and word document at once and then zip it into a folder, we run the following code from another Rscript file (rscript file needs to be in the same place where your `Rmd` source file is)

**file.R**

```
# create a folder where the multiple output files will be placed
dir.create("multiple_output")

# then render the source file to that created folder
rmarkdown::render(
  "multiple_outupt.Rmd", output_dir = "multiple_output/",
  output_format = "all"
)

# create file paths for zipping
files_for_zip <- dir('multiple_output', full.names = TRUE)

# zip the folder
zip(zipfile = "multiple_output", files = files_for_zip)
```

---

Then we will have the zipped folder `multiple_output.zip`.